# If there are two links with the same element name but are on different forms of a page how to specify one over the other?

Tags: watir, firewatir

[image]What I mean that in the inspection of 
my element I found that the two links 
have the same name but are on different forms. 
I want to click the second link.
How could I specify that in water?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser.form(how, what).link(how, what)
```

If you provide relevant HTML I can be more specific.

Comment: Inside of this page there are two separate forms. I have a picture I will attach of what I see when I inspect the elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got it to work using: browser.form(:name, "nameOfForm").submit

Answer (score 1):

The two links are each inside a div along with some unique text

Also despite the fact their text is the same the href is different.

This gives you two potential approaches

1) if you know the href won't change, then just address the link using that

```
browser.link(:href, 'javascript:document.poentryform.submit();').click
```

2) if the text won't change, and you can't be sure about the href, then refer to it via the outer container using a regular expression to match the known text

```
browser.div(:class => 'screenlet-title-bar', :text => /Purchase Order/).link(:text, 'Continue').click
```